# How to pass multiple list types as a parameter using the same method variable

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to pass multiple list types as a parameter using the same method variable and then loop through the types based on which type as been past. I tried using a generic method but it's not working.  Below are pseudo/example codes.  The List SAS_F_DISAGG_F  and List SAS_C_DISAGG_C  are SQL/Entity, and the List DisaggReportGroups is a class object.  I'm trying to pass the entity lists.

```
protected void GetReportGroup()
        {

           DisaggReportGroups rptGroup = new DisaggReportGroups();
           List<DisaggReportGroups> disagreportGroup = new List<DisaggReportGroups>();
           disagreportGroup.Add(rptGroup);

           DisaggregatedReportData disagReportData = new DisaggregatedReportData();

            foreach (var reportGroup in disagreportGroup)
            {

                if (reportGroup.FuturesOnly == "Futures Only, " & reportGroup.Agriculture == "Agriculture")
                {

                    List<SAS_F_DISAGG_F> futONlyDisagReportData = disagReportData.GetFuturesOnlyReportData(reportGroup.Agriculture).ToList();

                    CreateLongFormatReport<List<SAS_F_DISAGG_F>>(reportGroup.AgricultureFilenameFOLF, reportGroup.FuturesOnly, reportGroup.Agriculture, futONlyDisagReportData);

                }

                else if (reportGroup.FOCombined == "Futures and Options Combined, " & reportGroup.Agriculture == "Agriculture")
                {
                    List<SAS_C_DISAGG_C> combinedDisagReportData = disagReportData.GetFOCombinedReportData(reportGroup.Agriculture).ToList();

                    CreateLongFormatReport<List<SAS_C_DISAGG_C>>(reportGroup.AgricultureFilenameFOCombinedLF, reportGroup.FOCombined, reportGroup.Agriculture, combinedDisagReportData);
                }


            }

        }



protected void CreateFormatReport<T>(string filename, string disagCategory, string commSubGp, List<T> reportData) 
        {                                                       
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(@"~/Includes/") + filename, FileMode.Create))            
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                {

                    foreach (var value in reportData)
                    {

                        string FuturesOnly = "Futures Only, ";
                        string FOCombined = "Futures and Options Combined, ";
                        string reportCategory = "";


                        if (disagCategory == FuturesOnly)
                        {

                            reportCategory = FuturesOnly;
                        }
                        else if (disagCategory == FOCombined)
                        {
                            reportCategory = FOCombined;
                        }

                        string row01 = String.Format("{0, -10}{1, 29}{2, 8}", value.MKTTITL.PadRight(120), "Code -", value.Conmkt);

                        string row02 = String.Format("{0, -10}{1, 7}{2, 14}", "Blah Blah - ", reportCategory, value.DAT1TITL);


                        string row03 = String.Format("{0, 3}{1, 3}{2, 8:0,0}{3, 3}{4, 8:0,0}{5, 11:0,0}{6, 11:0,0}{7, 11:0,0}{8, 11:0,0}{9, 13:0,0}{10, 11:0,0}{11, 11:0,0}{12, 13:0,0}{13, 10:0,0}{14, 9:0,0}{15, 3}{16, 8:0,0}{17, 10:0,0}", "All",
                       colon, value.TA01, colon, value.TA02, value.TA03, value.TA04, value.TA05, value.TA06, value.TA07, value.TA08, value.TA09, value.TA10, value.TA11, value.TA12, colon, value.TA15, value.TA16);

                        string row04 = String.Format("{0, 3}{1, 3}{2, 8:0,0}{3, 3}{4, 8:0,0}{5, 11:0,0}{6, 11:0,0}{7, 11:0,0}{8, 11:0.##}{9, 13:0,0}{10, 11:0,0}{11, 11:0,0}{12, 13:0,0}{13, 10:0,0}{14, 9:0,0}{15, 3}{16, 8:0,0}{17, 10:0,0}", "Old",
                        colon, value.TO01, colon, value.TO02, value.TO03, value.TO04, value.TO05, value.TO06, value.TO07, value.TO08, value.TO09, value.TO10, value.TO11, value.TO12, colon, value.TO15, value.TO16);


                        writer.Write(row01);                        
                        writer.WriteLine(row02);
                        writer.WriteLine(row03);
                        writer.WriteLine(row04);


                    } //end foreach
                    writer.Close();
                } //end of stream writer

            }            
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem myself so I'm posting my solution for others that may need the same type of help.  The solution is to use Reflection within the foreach iteration.

```
foreach (var value in ReportData)
{
    //Reflection can be used
    string TA01 = value.GetType().GetProperty("TA01").GetValue(value).ToString();
    //...
    //...
    //do more stuff/coding...
}
```

Then in the String.Format change "value.TA01" to "TA01".  Do the same for all other variables.

Hope this help.